# stringi DLL load not working in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to install an R package that has a dependency on stringi. However, the installation is crashing with the following error message:

```
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/home/alexander/anaconda3/lib/R/library/stringi/libs/stringi.so':
  /home/alexander/anaconda3/lib/R/library/stringi/libs/stringi.so: undefined symbol: _ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEC1Ev
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/home/alexander/anaconda3/lib/R/library/stringi’
* restoring previous ‘/home/alexander/anaconda3/lib/R/library/stringi’
Error: Command failed (1)
```

Any help?